# Why my index match formula is not working?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, vlookup, nested-if

[image]

Column C (Box qty) and D (Box type) are my inputs here. Using index match i'm trying to retun the bin location (S1,S2,S3..etc) in column I by checking the Box type (810,811,911,822) and qty inside the table J to M which is pre fixed.

I used -1 in the end to get the next nearest lookup. Ex: ( if my box type is 810 and my box qty is 5 it should return S3 from bin location. I tried 1 before but it's returning the previous value S2. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the formula or any alternative to return the next nearest bin location?

Note: If the box qty same inside the table it should return the bin location that is matching exactly, the qty in between two numbers should return the next nearest bin location.

Comment: which match is not working?  simplify this into other cells to check/show to the team.  also edit the question to include the line #s. (i've coded Excel, but now just have a Mac, so it's a bit challenging to help...)

Comment: Column C (Box qty) and D (Box type) are my inputs here. Using index match I'm trying to return the bin location (S1, S2, S3..etc) in column I by checking the Box type (810,811,911,822) and qty inside the table J to M which is prefixed.

Comment: Ex:  if my box type is 810 and my box qty is 5 it should return S3 from the bin location.  and if my box type is 810 and my box qty is 4 it should return S2. The qty that lie in between should need to return the next nearest value not the previous one

Comment: As @Andrew stated, break each Match out into its own cell and see if it returns what you think it should.  You are going to need to do some debugging on your own.  The formula looks correct, so It may be something else.

Comment: Okay I'll try that

Comment: Do check all values are what you think they are. So for example text does not contain extra spaces etc

Comment: one this i suspect is -- are those referenced celled merged?  also, spaces/invisible chars (yes these do exist(i found a broken password w/ one)--can be found by <backspace> not moving)?

Comment: If you use **-1** in `MATCH` your data (here `$J$12:$M$17`) needs to be sorted descendingly from 96 to 2! If you change that, it should work!

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand. No, it's not merged. Should I need to check for spaces are something. Actually, the formula is working weirdly, I can return value for this scenario alone (Box qty(Col C)=1 Boxtype(Col D)=810 Location = R2 (Output) but the output of the formula should return S1 as in the reference in Col I to Col N. If I drag its showing #N/A.

Comment: @Qualia Hi, Yes it's working now. Thanks. I don't understand why the formula reading it reverese.